# Switch between QMainWindows

Tags: c++, qt

I have three `QMainWindow`s, `EntryWindow`, `WindowA`, `WindowB`. There are 2 buttons in `EntryWindow`, clicking `buttonA` displays `WindowA` and exits `EntryWindow`, clicking `buttonB` displays `WindowB` and exits `EntryWindow`.

In `main.cpp`:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QTextCodec::setCodecForCStrings(QTextCodec::codecForLocale());
    Entry w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

In `entryWindow.cpp`:

```
void Entry::on_chooseABtn_clicked()
{
    this->hide();
    WindowA w;
    w.show();
}

void Entry::on_chooseBBtn_clicked()
{
    this->hide();
    QTextCodec::setCodecForCStrings(QTextCodec::codecForLocale());
    WindowB w;
    w.show();
}
```

But this doesn't seem to work. After clicking the button, `WindowA` or `WindowB` just flashed off. How should I modify the code ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You create instances of WindowA and WindowB classes on stack:

```
WindowA w;
```

so they are deleted when method returns, just after

```
w.show();
```

Maybe add these windows as instance variables to `Entry` class.

EDIT: some code sample. In .h file:

```
class Entry : public QMainWindow {

//your stuff

private:

WindowA windowA;
WindowB windowB;

}
```

and you can change your button click handlers like that:

```
void Entry::on_chooseABtn_clicked()
{
    this->hide();
    windowA.show();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Create the windows as pointers, otherwise they get deleted automatically when they fall out of scope:

```
this->hide();
WindowA* w = new WindowsA(this);
w->show();
```

Comment: Correct, except there is no 'garbage collection' in C++ :)

Comment: w->setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose) can also be used if the object need not to be a member variable. It will automatically call delete on the object when the window is closed.

Comment: Works. But really don't get the garbage collection mechanism. Thanks !